# Laravel routes do not match where Application is within a subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, http, testing, phpunit

I have my Laravel application in a subdirectory as such:

```
https://www.example.com/subdirectory/api
```

This means that requests to the API are done as such:

```php
// GET https://www.example.com/subdirectory/api/user/1

// Meanwhile in api.php
Route::get('/user/{id}', 'controllerName@methodName');
```

And return as expected.

However when trying to set up feature tests of these endpoints using the `$this->get()` methods on the testcase my routes are not matching. This is seemingly happening because the entire subdirectory structure is being included in the final route:

```php
// In Test
$response = $this->get('/user/2');

// In api.php this no longer matches
Route::get('/user/{id}', 'controllerName@methodName'); 

// But this does
Route::get('/subdirectory/api/user/{id}', 'controllerName@methodName');
```

Basically the routing appears to work absolutely fine until queried from a test using ANY of the `json`/`get`/`post` etc. methods. The literal string URL in the request is completely fine (no duplication of the subdirectory etc.).

**Why are my routes matching for real queries but not these test queries?**

- My `APP_URL` is correctly set in all of my .env files
- I have tried fully describing the URL in the test json calls
- I have tried with/without the leading slash

Comment: I am not sure why you need to include `/subdirectory` as I have never put my Laravel application in a subdirectory but I did in a subdomain. For the `/api/user/{id}`, that is the way of doing it, how will Laravel know that `$this->get('/user/2');` is related to `/api/user/{id}` if you are not saying `/api` ? You must always use absolute path after `domain.com`.